# How does this Firebase onAuthStateChanged work in this code

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

I have an abstract question about Firebase. Here in [this](https://github.com/oluSammy/leadpreneur-admin/blob/master/src/App.js) code I wonder if the listener that is set up in the `useEffect` below is called if user is signed out?

I understand that when this code run the Firebase listener `onAuthStateChanged` below is attached and I wonder when user is signed out here or if user is signed out from another browser(signed in with the same credentials like Google/Facebook), will this code `onAuthStateChanged` run?

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.scss';
import Dashboard from './pages/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import Login from './pages/login-page/login.component';

import "react-loader-spinner/dist/loader/css/react-spinner-loader.css";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { setUser } from './Redux/User/user.actions';
import { selectUserSlice } from './Redux/User/user.selectors';
import { auth } from './firebase/firebase.utils';

const App = ({ setCurrentUser, currentUser }) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    const unSubscribeFromAuth = auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      setCurrentUser(user);
    });
    //cleanup function
    return () => {
      unSubscribeFromAuth();
    }
  },[setCurrentUser])

  return(
    <div className="App">
      {
        currentUser ? <Dashboard />   : <Login />
      }
    </div>
  )
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  setCurrentUser: user => dispatch(setUser(user)),
});

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  currentUser: selectUserSlice(state)
})


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Firebase Authentication a user is signed in to that specific browser instance. So if the user signs in or out in one browser, it has no effect on any other browser instances.

Keep in mind that different tabs are part of the same browser instance, while even separate windows **may** be part of the same browser instance - depending on the browser and how the window was opened.

But for example, if the browser are on different machines, or if they're say Firefox, Edge and Chrome, the `onAuthStateChanged` listener on one of these browser instances will not be called with sign-in state changes that are caused by another one.

Comment: On Android if the app is installed on two devices and same user is signed in on both I think the onAuthStateChanged is fired on both devices If I don't remember wrong?

Comment: But how can one detect this in the browser using Rectjs?

Comment: Nope, on Android too it will only fire on the device where you are signed in. The only type of difference would be if the server refuses to renew your token, for example when your account is disabled. In that case all devices would be unable to refresh the user's ID token and would sign the user out (and this fire the auth state listener) when that happens. But this will take up to an hour (as that's how long the token is valid), so chances are that there may be quite some time difference between when it happens on different deviecs.